# Клиенты не могут установить соединение с веб-сервером на SSL

Tags: python, веб-сервер, ssl, flask, socketio-client

написал `flask`-приложение, которое использует `gevent` и `socketio`,
у меня имеется скрипт, который я привожу внизу,
он, собственно, запускает SSL по указанному мною адресу в файле конфигурации и функционирует без каких-либо проблем:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import configparser
import ssl
from app import create_app, socketio

app = create_app()

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

ctx = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ctx.load_cert_chain('/path_to_the_cert','path_to_the_key')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, config['server']['host'], int(config['server']['port']), ssl_context=ctx)
```

Также у меня имеется клиент-бот, который пытается подсоединиться к серверу по адресу через файл конфигурации, что-то вроде `https://config['server']['host']:int(config['server']['port']`, и он даже подключается безо всяких проблем, но при этом сервер выдает следующие ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 190, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
  File "/home/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 65, in wrap_socket
    _session=session)
  File "/home/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 238, in __init__
    raise x
  File "/home/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 234, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/home/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 561, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:833)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 537, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 26, in _handle_and_close_when_done
    return handle(*args_tuple)
  File "/home/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 193, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    ssl_socket.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ssl_socket' referenced before assignment
Tue Apr 24 16:57:43 2018 <Greenlet at 0x7f0069b295a0: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method StreamServer.wrap_socket_and_handle , <bound method StreamServer.do_close of <WSGIServer, (<gevent._socket3.socket [closed]  object, fd=-1, )> failed with UnboundLocalError
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему с подключением клиента к веб-серверу? Может быть, я как-то неправильно запускаю веб-сервер на SSL? Или мой клиент должен быть каким-то образом авторизован, чтобы получить доступ к серверу?
Есть ли какие-то другие варианты именно через скрипт на питоне?

Comment: Не по теме вопроса: по-моему правильнее всего пускать все соединения через nginx, а SSL настраивать уже в нём

Comment: По теме вопроса: если вы используете сертификаты от Let's Encrypt, значит вы про chain забыли наверно. А если вы используете самоподписанные сертификаты, то они и не должны работать вообще

Comment: @andreymal касательно первого: я настроил SSL на порт 8000 через nginx, так как мне необходимо предоставить доступ к определенным директориям через 8000, а вот мое приложение должно работать через порт 5000, будет ли оно функционировать, если я не буду кодить это в скрипте, а просто в default конфигурации уточню, что порт 5000 тоже должен быть на SSL?
Касательно второго: использую официальные сертификаты, и, вроде бы, chain у меня в коде выше определена и описана...

Comment: Про chain я имею в виду вторую часть сертификата — Let's Encrypt делит сертификат на два файла cert.pem и chain.pem, и вот второй файл нужно тоже не забывать подключать. Ну или можно подключить сразу объединённый файл fullchain.pem (но я не в курсе, как это делается в питоне, и поэтому написать полноценный ответ не могу, просто информация к размышлению)